# Regex - replace space in string that has '.com Capital letter' with new line

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string with a space that I need to replace. The pattern is `.com` followed by a space and then any capital letter.

An example would be:
`".com T"`

The space between the `.com` and `T` needs to be replaced by a new line.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write such a regular expression yourself yet? Post what you've tried

Comment: Construct your regex here: http://regex101.com - make sure to switch to pythons syntax. After finishing it use `re.sub` from the `re` - module and code the python prog to do it.

Comment: This will take me an hour to figure out as I don't know regex and I'm already running short on sleep. @PatrickArtner Thank you, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex.  `Lookbehind & Lookahead`

Ex:

```
import re
l = "AAS asdasd asdasd Hello.com T"

m = re.sub("(?<=.com)(\s+)(?=[A-Z])", r"\n", l)
print(m)
```

**Output:**

```
AAS asdasd asdasd Hello.com
T
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to replace spaces after `.com` before a capital letter:

```
import re

data = """some.com Tata

dir.com Wube

asa.com alas

null.com 1234
"""

pattern = r'(\.com)(\s)([A-Z])' # captures .com as \1 and the capital letter as \3
repl = r"\1\n\3"                # replaces the match with \1+newline+\3

print(re.sub(pattern,repl,data))
```

Output:

```
some.com
Tata

dir.com
Wube

asa.com alas

null.com 1234
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/hYOb3a/1

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub`

```
import re
text = re.sub(r'\.com\s+([A-Z])', r'.com\n\1', text)
```